# Show modal dialog when document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using [custombox](http://dixso.github.io/custombox/) jQuery plugin and I would like to make appears a modal dialog when the page is ready.

This is my current code (JS part):

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $.fn.custombox( this, {
            overlay: true,
            effect: 'blur',
            url:  '#modal'
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

And this code (HTML part):

```
<div id="modal" style="display: none;" class="modal-example-content">
    <div class="modal-example-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" onclick="$.fn.custombox('close');">&times;</button>
        <h4>jQuery Custombox</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-example-body">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I hope someone can tell me how to make it works.

Comment: try replacing `this` with `#modal`

Comment: hmmm it isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing 'this' to the function, you must pass the right element. So select the modal div first. Try this code:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var modal = document.getElementById('modal');

        $.fn.custombox( modal, {
            overlay: true,
            effect: 'blur',
            url:'#modal'
        });
    });
</script>
```